# How to get the lines from a list of IP addresses which has the fourth octet more than 10?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, ip-address

I have the following output:

```
netman@netman:~/Desktop$ nmap -p 80,443,8080 --open 172.20.74.0/24 | grep report | cut -d"(" -f2 | cut -d")" -f1 | sed '/172.20.74.(0-9)/d'
172.20.74.4
172.20.74.11
172.20.74.40
172.20.74.212
```

I need a way ( sed or awk or any other command) to get the IP addresses in the range 172.20.74.11 - 172.20.74.255

I tried Sed and another commands like grep, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{a="172.20.74.";for(i=11;i<255;i++)print a i}' ???

Comment: @A-Ray I think he wants to filter his list for ones with a final octet >10

Comment: You can do it with an extended regex but my unix box doesn't do that so the easiest way to do it on my unix box is to filter out the ones you don't want: `... | grep "^172\.20\.74\." | grep -v "\.[0-9]$" | grep -v "\.10$"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
. . . | awk '-F.' '$4>10'
```

produces output

```
172.20.74.11
172.20.74.40
172.20.74.212
```

from the 4 IPs you included above.  Did I understand your need correctly?

This approach relies on awks ability to operate on numbered fields based on specifing an alternate value for `FS` (Field Separator). I have used the command-line option `'-F.'` to set `FS`.

Because you want the 4th field, we only need compare `$4>10`. Only lines that match that comparison are printed.

A long hand version would be

```
 . . . | awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{if ($4 > 10) print $0}'
```

where `$0` refers to the whole line of input and `$4` refers to the 4th field in the line, when using the '.' as the Field Separator and the default action is to process (test) all lines of input (in this example, coming from your pipeline).

IHTH

Comment: Hi all,

Thank you for your efforts and the answer.

yes that 's what I was looking for.

In my awk command, I was missing the "delimiter" dot.

Thank you for showing the way...

Dharmesh

Comment: @DharmeshMithbavkar : I'm glad that helped. I've edited answer with more detail, so check that out. Good luck to all.